# Removing excess ">" in string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

In my code I get a string which have html tags like so:

```
$string = '<div style="width:100px;">ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span></div>';
```

Now, I removed the style attribute from the said string using preg_replace:

```
$string = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '', $string);
```

After removing the style tag, I managed to remove the style attribute so the div tag ended up looking like `<div>`. The problem, I encountered after doing this is that I now get an excess `>` after the closing tag for the span so the string looks like this now:

```
$string = '<div>ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span>   >     </div>';
```

My question is, why did I suddenly get an exccess `>`? Is there a different regular expression I can use that will get rid of the style attribute without the additional `>` appearing? Or is there any way I can get ride of this?

I tried using str_replace twice like so:

```
$string = str_replace("\n", "", $string);
$string = str_replace(">>", ">", $string);
```

But that did not work either.

I am not trying to remove the HTML tags, just the style part.

Comment: [Avoid processing HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3577662/19068)

Comment: your string is wrong you should use something like this `$string='<div style="width:100px;">ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span></div>'`

Comment: What is your full replace code? not just the regular expression.

Comment: Can't reproduce your result string. I get `<div>ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span></div>` as result of the replace only.

Comment: I think I was getting the said ">" because there were more html tags on my string. In any case, using addslashes before the preg_replace instead of the other way around seems to have done the trick. Thanks for all the assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use it only for this string.

```
<?php
$string = "<div style=\"width:100px;\">ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span></div>";

$string = strip_tags($string,"<span>");

$string = "<div>".$string."</div>";
?>
```

Now the string is:

```
<div>ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span></div>
```

Comment: Thanks I'll try this. Perhaps all I need are the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

I used This

```
$string = '<div style="width:100px;">ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span></div>';
$output = preg_replace('/(<[^>]+) style=".*?"/i', '$1', $string);
die(htmlentities($output))
```

and the output is

```
<div>ABC 1234 <span> Test string, testing this string</span></div>
```

as you need

Comment: This is exactly what I did that ended up with the excess ">"